# RDS - SQL server agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Intention/requirement is to run a stored procedure in certain interval.

1. How to configure SQL server agent in Amazon RDS?
2. Is there any alternative for of SQL server agent in RDS which can help us to run procedures like concurrent programs/cron jobs?

Comment: i don't think any database as service has sql agent.In azure ,you can  use azure elastic jobs,not sure rds

Comment: trying to follow - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html

Answer (score 2):

RDS does have the SQL Agent starting at the Web version (it is not enabled at the Express license), and it works well.

One thing to note is that the time schedule always need to be at UTC timezone, it is not possible to change it.

Comment: Any alternate for Express Edition??

Comment: You can write a script at any language and execute it with the Windows Scheduler.